# Use Carrierwave with a one to many relation between models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, carrierwave, has-many

**Stage**

Image a gallery application.
I have two models `Handcraft` and `Photos`.
*One handcraft may have many photos*, suppose I have models like this:

- `Handcraft(name:string)`
- `Photo(filename:string, description:string, ...)`

In `_form.html.erb` of handcrafts, there is:

```
<%= form_for @handcraft, html: {multipart: true} do |f| %>
  # ... other model fields

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :photo %><br />
    <%= f.file_field :photo %>
  </div>

  # ... submit button
<% end %>
```

`handcraft.rb` looks like this:

```
class Handcraft < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :photo
  has_many :photos
  mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader
  # ... 
end
```

`photo_uploader.rb`:

```
class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::RMagick

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_limit => [100, 100]
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
end
```

**Problem**

When I submit form, it throws this error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `photo_will_change!' for #<Handcraft:0xb66de424>):
```

**Question**

How should I use/configure Carrierwave in this case?

Answer (score 11):

You need to mount the uploader on the field that will store the filename, so your models should look like

```
class Handcraft < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :photos
  # ... 
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :filename, :description
  mount_uploader :filename, PhotoUploader
  # ... 
end
```

and then as it seems you'll be creating the photos through the handcraft form, you should add

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos
```

in your `Handcraft` class

Then your form will look something like

```
<%= form_for @handcraft, html: {multipart: true} do |f| %>
  # ... other model fields

  <%= f.fields_for :photos do |photo| %>
    <%= photo.label :photo %><br />
    <%= photo.file_field :photo %>
  <% end %>

  # ... submit button
<% end %>
```

For the form to display fields for photo, you'll need your `Handcraft` instance to have `photos` created, this can be done in your `new` method in the `HandcraftsController` like that:

```
def new
  @handcraft = Handcraft.new
  4.times { @handcraft.photos.build }
end
```

This will make 4 (arbitrary number) fields availables in your form, if somehow you want the user to dynamically add new photos in your form, have a look at [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form)